# doctrine2 check OneToOne related entity exists in DB

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

Entity has OneToOne relation declared

```
/**
 * @var \Backend\SalesBundle\Entity\SalesOrder
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Backend\CatalogBundle\Entity\CatalogProduct")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="product_id")
 * })
 */
private $product;
```

Following code will work in both cases. If database entry exists and if it doesn't

```
{{ item.product.productId }}
```

But when i call for field that needs to be loaded from database i have "Entity was not found." exception. All twig tests i know are not suitable for checking this because of Doctrine Proxies

```
{{ item.product.name }}
{{ item.product is null }}
{{ item.product is empty }} etc.
```

Is there any elegant way to check if related entity exists? I can do it like this, but it's not good enough for me because i steel need to call {{ item.product.productId }}

```
public function getProduct()
{
    try {
        $sku = $this->product->getSku();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException $e) {
        return null;
    }

    return $this->product;
}
```

Comment: @TheLittlePig If i use lazy load product always exists. And error appears when query is executed and related entity not found. Solution for me is using fetch="EAGER" when product data is fetched the same time as root entity. In this case product will be nulled.

Comment: If i prefer lazyload this also works public function getProduct()
    {
        try {
            $sku = $this->product->getSku();
        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException $e) {
            return null;
        }
        
        return $this->product;
    }

Answer (score 0):

@andreysaf, try default filter.

```
{{ item.product.name|default }}
```

It prevents throwing exceptions if no product exists.
In fact it prints passed string (by default string is empty line).

Comment: Much better. Now it looks like an answer - a slightly "softened" answer, because of the "try", but an answer.

Comment: By the way, you do not need to address the asker. A notification of a new answer is implicit.